# How to add a class to the called component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know how to add a class to the header component, which I'm calling from another page. I wanted to know how I add that change class, how it looks here

```
const [change, setChange] = useState("change");

const listenScrollEvent = (e) => {
  if (window.scrollY < 400) {
    return setChange("change");
  } else if (window.scrollY > 400) {
    return setChange("changeColor");
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", listenScrollEvent);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", listenScrollEvent);
  };
}, []);

return <Header className={change} />;
```

Header Code:

```
export default function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="container header">
      <Logo />
      <Navbar />
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add Header code. Which div/span/element exactly do you want to add class on?

Comment: There is this, I want to add the class to change the color of my logo and nav bar when it reaches 400px

Comment: Look at @camilo's answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, thanks you anyway

Comment: Btw, I think you can drop off all the `window.` since everything inside it is already globally available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept `className` as a prop on your `Header` component.

Something like this:

```
export default function Header({ className }) {
    return (
        <header className={`container header ${className}`}>
            <Logo />
            <Navbar />
        </header>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to react noob doubt

Comment: @fanjiooJr no problem. If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted.